# session class not keeping track of session id corectly

Tags: php, session, pdo

This is the session class I'm using.
Is it a good idea to regenerate the session id on every page as that is what I intend to do.
Regenerating the session id on every page the write function does this 0 (the rowCount())selected 0 key selected from the getkey function 1 inserted.
The read function will work good where (from rowCount()) 1 selected 1 key from getkey function, and 1 destroyed from the destroy function. 
Sometimes I will get 0 read data records selected successfully
0 destroy delete records successfully, from the destroy function yet it should  have selected in the read function then the getkey function then the destroy function because the id in the where clause is the one in the data base table. 
Other times I'll get 1read selected 0 key records selected successfully 0delete  yet the old session id has been deleted and the new is inserted(from the write function) as if 1 read selected 1 key selected and 1 destroyed.
With the read function the id for the where clause, will be the one that it should be able to select, the one in the db. This is the same the key and delete functions.
Sometimes I'll get two id trying to be inserted as another has been generated but wont if the same time as set_time is set to unique in the db but if not the same time (testing go another page)I'll have another row with a  different id in the db table. Sometimes just a wrong id(not the one from the write function) in the right row. No new row just a different id. The session id is the primary key in the db table. I do seem to be having a problem such as one click of mouse and it seems like two at times, could that be a cause.Greatful for any help.
PS:  .............5.2.16
With the situation 1 read selected 0 key selected 0 destroy or if 1 read selected 1 key 1 destroy; saying the id for those where clauses is 123. At the end of the php section of the page $id = session_id() and echo $id and it's; let's say 321. Then after the bottom of the page where messages echoed.
0 key results selected and the id for that where clause is 321.
Then encrypted is echoed. Then 0 write selected 1 write inserted successfully.
Is that normal

```
enter code here

     class session{
 function __construct(){
//set our custom session functions.
session_set_save_handler(array($this,'open'),array($this,'close'),array   ($this,'read'),array($this,'write'),array($this,'destroy'),array($this,'gc'));
//This line prevents unexpected effects when using objects as save handlers.
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
 }
 function start_session($session_name,$secure){
  $httponly = true;
 // hash algorithm to use for the session id.(use hash_algos() to get a list of available hashs.)
  $session_hash = 'sha512';
 // check if hash is available
 if(in_array($session_hash,hash_algos())){
 // set the hash function.
  ini_set('session.hash_function',$session_hash);
 }
  // how many bits per character of the hash.
  ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character',5);
 // force the session to only use cookies, not url variables.
  ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',1);
  //get session cookie parameters
 $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
 $domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
 session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],$cookieParams["path"],
  //$cookieparams["domain"],$secure,$httponly);
 $domain,$secure,$httponly);
  // change session name
  session_name($session_name);
  session_name('identitysession');
  // now we can start the session
  session_start();
   // this line regenerates the session and delete the old one.
  // it also generates a new encryption key in the database.
 session_regenerate_id(true);
   }

 protected $db = null;


 function open(){
  if(is_null($this->db)){
 $user = 'myuser'; 
 $pass = 'mypassword';
 try{
   $this->db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname= mydb',$user,$pass,
   array(
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    =>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
   PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES =>false));
  }catch (PDOException $e){
   echo 'Connection failed:'.$e->getMessage();
   }
  echo 'open open','<br/>';// the echo for testing
  return true;
  }
      else{
    echo 'not open','<br/>';// the echo for testing
    exit();
   }
 }



 function close(){
  $this->db = null;
  echo 'closed closed','<br/>';// the echo for testing
  return true;
 }


 function read($id){
  $timeout = time()-(30*60);
  echo $id,'<br/>';// the echo for testing
 if(!isset($this->read_stmt)){
     try{
     $this->read_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id,data,set_time FROM mydbtable WHERE id= :id LIMIT 1 ");
     }catch(PDOException $e){
     echo 'Unable to select from database read:'.$e->getMessage();
     }
 }

   if(isset($this->read_stmt)){
  $this->read_stmt->bindParam(':id',$id, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
  $this->read_stmt->execute();
  $row = $this->read_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $idrow = $row['id'];
  echo 'selected id <br/>' . $idrow,'<br/>';// the echo for testing the selected id of db
  $read_count = $this->read_stmt->rowCount();
  echo $read_count. " Read data records selected successfully<br/>";// the echo for testing

       if($read_count > 0 && $row !=''){
         $data =$row['data'];
         $time_past = $row['set_time'];
           if( $time_past < $timeout){
       echo 'nogood time out';//not completed yet
           }
               elseif($time_past > $timeout){
               echo 'read getting data','<br/>';// the echo for testing
               $key = $this->getkey($id);
               echo 'selected id for key <br/>' . $id,'<br/>';// the echo for testing
               $data = $this->decrypt($data, $key);
               echo 'Data','<br/>';// the echo for testing
               echo $data,'<br/>';// the echo for testing
               return $data;
               }
    }   
        elseif($read_count < 1 && $row ==''){
        return '';
        } 
   } 
 }


  function write($id, $data){   
    $key = $this->getkey($id);
    $data = $this->encrypt($data, $key);
    $time = time();
        if(!isset($this->w_stmt)){
        try{
    $this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM mydbtable WHERE id= :id LIMIT 1 ");
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Unable to select from database:'.$e->getMessage();
        }
        }

  if(isset($this->w_stmt)){
   try{
   $this->w_stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
       $row = $this->w_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       }catch(PDOException $e){
       echo 'Unable something from database:'.$e->getMessage();
       }    
       $w_count = $this->w_stmt->rowCount(); 
       echo $w_count. "W stmt records selected successfully";// the echo for testing

   if($w_count > 0 && $row !=''){
   try{
    $this->w_stmt =$this->db->prepare("UPDATE mydbtable SET id = :id, 
   set_time = :time,data = :data, session_key = :session_key");
    $this->w_stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id,':time'=>$time,':data'=>$data,
   ':session_key'=>$key));
   $wri_count = $this->w_stmt->rowCount(); 
   echo $wri_count. "records updated successfully";// the echo for testing
   }catch (PDOException $e){
  echo 'Can not update  the database:'.$e->getMessage();// the echo for testing
   }      
   }
       elseif($w_count < 1 && $row == ''){
            try{
    $this->w_stmt =$this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO mydbtable (id,set_time,data,session_key)
            VALUES(:id,:time,:data,:session_key)");
            $this->w_stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id,':time'=>$time,':data'=>$data,
    ':session_key'=>$key));
            $write_count = $this->w_stmt->rowCount();    
            echo $write_count. "w stmt records inserted successfully<br/>";// the echo for testing
            echo $id;
        }catch (PDOException $e){
            echo 'Can not insert the database:'.$e->getMessage();
           }   
         }
  }// if  set 
   }


   function destroy($id){
     echo $id,'<br/>';// the echo for testing
           if(!isset($this->delete_stmt)){
       try{
           $this->delete_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM mydbtable WHERE id = :id");
          }catch(PDOException $e){
          echo 'Unable to delete from database:'.$e->getMessage();
          }
      }

   if(isset($this->delete_stmt)) {
   $this->delete_stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);  
   $this->delete_stmt->execute();
   $delete_count = $this->delete_stmt->rowCount();
   echo $delete_count . " destroy delete records successfully<br/>";// the echo for testing
   echo 'delete ','<br/>';// the echo for testing
   return true;
   } 
   }


    function gc($max){
        if(!isset($this->gc_stmt)){
    try{
        $this->gc_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM mydbtable WHERE set_time < :set_time");
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Unable to delete from database:'.$e->getMessage();
        }
        }

   if(isset($this->gc_stmt)){
    $old = time() - $max;
    $this->gc_stmt->execute(array(':set_time'=>$old));
    $gc_count = $this->gc_stmt->rowCount();
    echo $gc_count. " gc records  successfully";// the echo for testing
   }
  return true;
  }


  private function getkey($id){
   echo $id,'<br/>';// the echo for testing
       if(!isset($this->key_stmt)){
    try{
        $this->key_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT session_key FROM mydbtable WHERE id = :id limit 1");
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Unable to select from database for key:'.$e->getMessage();
        } 
        }

    if(isset($this->key_stmt)){
    $this->key_stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    $row = $this->key_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $key_count = $this->key_stmt->rowCount();
    echo $key_count. " key records selected successfully<br/>";

      if($key_count > 0 && $row !=''){
              echo 'key getting key','<br/>';// the echo for testing
              $key = $row['session_key'];
              return $key;
      }
              elseif($key_count < 1 && $row == ''){
          $random_key = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()),true));
              return $random_key;
      }       
           }
     }


    private function encrypt($data,$key){
    $salt = 'cH!swe!retReGu7W6bEDRup7usuDUh9THeD2CHeGE*ewr4n39=E@rAsp7c-Ph@pH';
    $key = substr(hash('sha256',$salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    echo 'encrypted','<br/>';// the echo for testing
    return $encrypted;
    } 


    private function decrypt($data, $key){
    $salt = 'cH!swe!retReGu7W6bEDRup7usuDUh9THeD2CHeGE*ewr4n39=E@rAsp7c-Ph@pH';
    $key = substr(hash('sha256',$salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    echo 'decript','<br/>';// the echo for testing
   return $decrypted;
  }
```

Comment: Can anybody actually read that code fragment? Format and CODE Indentation is a key to simpifying the debugging process

Comment: Can anybody read the problem description? Make your question easy to read and people may stay long enough to read it!

Comment: Could you provide an isolated piece of problem code and a specific question? I tried to edit your text blurb, but honestly I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: @Peehaa It seems to be the read function as I can't tell what is going on. A specific question going through when going to a page and doesn't seem to be specific page, I got from the read select (from the rowCount()) 1 read selected, we'll say the id for the where clause is 638c. Then 0 key selected  and the id for the where clause is 638c. Then 0 destroy  and the id for the where clause is 638c. The write function has 0 selected 0key selected 1 insert and that id inserted is 9123 and looking in the table there is no new row and the id inserted is 9123. in the process it has tried to decrypt

Comment: @Ryan Vincent  the threats and this is in development and having read a bit about regenerating the id I would think better if it is at the least at times such as say going to checkout or if a log in. Administration is another area of course. Is it an over kill to regenerate on each page on a site no log in yet admin each page and also very limited numbers use admin. Basically what sort of problems are there with regenerating  and it is about threats and weighing those threats with the need so to speak. Threats come in many shapes and many directions, unknown.